# formato de fecha en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un campo del tipo **varchar** donde almaceno fechas con el formato `d/m/y` ejemplo `"5/6/2022"` y quiero convertirlo a tipo `date`, en la misma base de datos, pasando a otro campo de tipo `date`. He intentado:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(fcfacfemi, '%d-%m-%y') FROM FCFAC where id =1
```

Siempre obtengo un error.

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo? También intente:

```
update fcfac set femi =convert(fcfacfemi,'Y/m/d')
```

`femi` es mi campo de tipo `date`
`fcfacfemi` es mi campo de tipo **varchar** donde esta la fecha en formato string.

Comment: siempre obtengo una error.. cual?

Comment: me devuelve valor Null como respuesta... me decia warnig stament ... algo asi le di no volver a mostrar el mensaje y de salir pero siempre devuelve valor nulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando `-` y, según dices, las fechas contienen `/`.

Por otro lado, si tu fecha viene así: `5/6/2022` interpeto que:

- el día tiene el formato `0 ... 31`
- el mes tiene el formato `0 ... 12`
- el año tiene el formato de cuatro dígitos

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), debes usar entonces las letras `e` para el día, `c` para el mes y `Y` para el año, de lo contrario te expones a actualizar las fechas erróneamente.

Así debería funcionar:

```
UPDATE fcfac
    SET femi = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(femi, '%e/%c/%Y'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(femi, '%e/%c/%Y')) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: La acomode asi segun tu ejemplo: UPDATE fcfac
    SET femi = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(fcfacfemi, '%d/%m/%Y'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(fcfacfemi, '%d/%m/%Y')) IS NOT NULL and id =1; y Resulto de maravilla Mil Gracias despues de 3 dias como loco.... me salvaste Bro.

Comment: @EdwinMisericordia revisa la nueva edición. Al parecer el día y el mes vienen en un formato determinado y deberías usar las letras específicas para ese formato, de lo contrario algunas fechas podrían ser erróneas al actualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando date_format, sería algo así:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fcfacfemi, "%d-%m-%y")
  FROM FCFAC where id =1;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Intente hacer eso Ignacio Barria .....de ahi mismo probe varias opciones pero solo recibo valores nulos como resultado, las fechas tienen este formato.. ejemplo "7/1/2021" mi idea era convertira a formato "07/01/2021" pero no encuentro como hacerlo... y de ahi llegue a pedir ayuda por aqui.. el campo fcfacfemi es de tipo varchar... para aclarar.

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos por su tiempo..

```
UPDATE fcfac
    SET femi = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(fcfacfemi, '%d/%m/%Y'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(fcfacfemi, '%d/%m/%Y')) IS NOT NULL and id =1;
```

al final quedo asi..

Comment: si te fijas bien no es la misma pero lo tomare muy cuenta vengo aprendiendo a diario, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.. un abrazo.

Comment: Si decís que no es la misma, entonces explicá _qué hace la consulta_. Tal vez vos comprendas cómo funciona, pero otros usuarios que podrían tener un problema similar puede que no. Leé [answer]. Además, ojo con lo que te dijeron en el comentario de la respuesta aceptada.